# Ok, why was my network profile not used?

Tags: support

Created my account using the Join button as I usually do and I ended up with a default profile icon and a `user1234` name. Even editing my network profile and clicking "save to all public network sites" won't update my profile here. I had to change my name for just this site specifically and I can't find a "import from network" option.

What gives?